# Magento 2 - How to add a custom column in customer grid like (is approved)

Tags: magento-2.1, column, custom-column-grid

i want to add a custom column in customer grid like "is_approved" customer section.
please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First you need to create an **customer attribute** `is_approve`

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/Setup/InstallData.php

**Note** Make sure you add `'is_used_in_grid' => true,` in your attribute options or you may get sql error.

```
<?php 

namespace Namespace\Modulename\Setup; 

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactor
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;    

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }    

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {
         /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'is_approve', [
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => 'Is Approved',
            'input' => 'select',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 1001,
            'position' => 1001,
            'is_used_in_grid' => true,
            'system' => 0,
            'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
            'adminhtml_only'=>1,
            'default'=>0
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'is_approve')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
        ]);

        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

- Display it in the customer listing create ui component

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <column name="is_approve">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Is Approved</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">51</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

- Finally add the attribute to the **customer grid index**

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/etc/indexer.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Indexer/etc/indexer.xsd">
    <indexer id="customer_grid">
        <fieldset name="customer">
            <field name="is_approve" xsi:type="filterable" dataType="int"/>
        </fieldset>
    </indexer>
</config>
```

- run command `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` and check.

Comment: but i think custom attribute is not created and all my customers are not showing now

Comment: after removing this code all customers are displaying

Comment: Check your database if your attribute is created. Also check in logs if there are any errors found.

Comment: check which block is getting error. There must be some typo error. It works fine for me

Comment: which table to check in database

Comment: You can check the `eav_attribute` table. It may be possible if the attribute is not found its giving you an column not found error and so your customer are not displayed. You can also check in this when your customer collection response.

Comment: yes nothing is created in `eav_attribute` table and also all customers are not displaying now, but at first time my column was displaying in the customer grid in admin panel but nothing was created in `eav_attribute` table

Comment: remove your module from `setup_module` table and then run the command `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Comment: yes i deleted all the files that u told to create and ran `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` this command now my customers are back

Comment: but now what to do to create a custom attribute,

Comment: all i want is two options (pending, approved) in a select element at customer columns

Comment: I had mentioned the table. Remove your module entry from database search in this table `setup_module`. Then run the `setup:upgrade` command this will initiate your install script and will install the attribute

Comment: got error something went wrong in popup

Comment: debug it check your console for errors.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'is_approve' in 'order clause', query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `customer_grid_flat` AS `main_table` ORDER BY is_approve ASC LIMIT 20

Comment: So your attribute is not created. Check your install script there seems to be an error there. Also make sure you have added `'is_used_in_grid' => true,` in your attribute option when creating your attribute.

Comment: its already there and i copied and paste your code without any change but with namespace on top. `namespace Learning\HelloPage\Setup; `

Comment: one thing i wanna ask, when new customer is register what is his status for first time

Comment: The `'default' => 0` value is set to 0 so 0 will be saved.

Comment: If the solution has worked for you. You can accept it and upvote it so other users may be benefited.

Comment: ofcourse man,  i registered a new customer and its `is_approved` is nor `yes` and nor `no`

Comment: @Priyank After adding customer attribute it shows error while we export customer in Magento 2.1.10. error: https://www.screencast.com/t/RTe2pEphTPI

Comment: I also getting error while export data.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. I have created my own module. My custom attribute is from another table and another module so ihave created this module.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/237030/63460