# Add custom column and filter to customer grid from joined table in magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer-grid, custom-column-grid

I need to add custom column and filter in the customer grid in Magento 2 admin. The column attribute is from different modules. There are many solutions for sales order grid, but none (or incomplete) for customer grid.

I had the same issue, so I found the solution by myself. The solution is in the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the module i have created.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=13l29KVZSekCBEmzNtuxc3FsqjoCI9UL1

Comment: I don't have any custom table now, I just created an attribute in the customer, and created a customer_listing.xml and a data provider, so that case how can  I use this with out any custom table

Comment: fix the issues 
it has some fatal errors

Answer (score 1):

you can add custom column in customer grid by this

**customer_listing.xml**

path : app\code\vender\module\view\adminhtml\ui_component\

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
   <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
    <column name="custom_columns_name_same_as_field_in_db">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">55</item>
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">My Custom Column</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
</columns>
</listing>
```

**CustomerDataProvider.php**

path : app\code\vender\module\Ui\Component\Listing\

```
<?php

namespace vender\module\Ui\Component\Listing;

class CustomerDataProvider extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult
{
    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();
        $this->getSelect()->joinLeft
        (
            ['custom_table_name' => $this->getTable('custom_table_name')],
            'main_table.entity_id = custom_table_name.customer_id',
            ['filed_you_want_to_display']
        );
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**di.xml**

path : app\code\vender\module\etc

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection2" />
    <virtualType name="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection2" type="Tatva\Corerewrite\Ui\Component\Listing\CustomerDataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">customer_grid_flat</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

Comment: I have already tried this solution but it didn't work. So, i made module which worked for me.

Comment: what is Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection2

Answer (score 0):

@Hiren, thx for this solution that works on magento 2.2, but doesn't not work since I've upgrade to 2.4.
Now I have an error :
Call to undefined method {vendor}\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\CustomerDataProvider\Interceptor::addFullTextFilter()
Exception in /home/www/website/www/vendor/magento/module-customer/Ui/Component/Listing/FulltextFilter.php:32

Any Ideas ?

Edit : to be sharper the error occurs when I made a search.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/207309)